# MVC5 Details/Edit/Delete with Multi-Key Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, multikey

Pretty new to MVC5 but gaining ground quickly.  This small issue has me stumped and  there does not seem to be much information on Goolge (or I am not asking Google the right questions).

I have a Table (FILE_RCPTS_LOG)
This table has multi keys (2)
First Key is Field:  TRACK_NMBR (int)
Second Key is Field: TRANS_DT (date)

When I created my Controller, the default views were also created.  And for the most part, they work fine.  However, I am getting HttpNotFound Errors, when attempting to use the Edit\Delete\Details links

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {/* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
```

This would be fine, if my table only had one key.  But how do I pass both keys?

The few solutions I found online seemed way to complicated for such a simple action.  I think I am missing something obvious here . . .

This is the code for my controller (Details)

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id, DateTime id2)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        FILE_RCPTS_LOG fILE_RCPTS_LOG = await db.FILE_RCPTS_LOG.FindAsync(id);
        if (fILE_RCPTS_LOG == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(fILE_RCPTS_LOG);
    }
```

I have tried several ways of passing multiple keys, but nothing is working.  I have read a few tutorials about using SPLIT but I could not get that working either.  This seems like such a simple and very common thing, as I would think most tables have multi-keys.

Is there a simple way of doing this that I am not seeing?  I feel like I am over-thinking it.

thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this. The first, in ActionLink, pass all 2 key values in as a comma delimited string. For example in Detail action:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {id= @item.TRACK_NMBR +','+@item.TRANS_DT});
```

In Details ActionController, you need to parse each of the 2 keys out.

```
string[] splitid = id.Split(',');
            FILE_RCPTS_LOG obj = db.FILE_RCPTS_LOG.Find(Convert.ToInt32(splitid[0]),Convert.ToDateTime(splitid[1]));
```

Or you can transfer 2 params as your solution:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {id= @item.TRACK_NMBR, id2 =@item.TRANS_DT});

public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id, DateTime id2)
{
FILE_RCPTS_LOG obj = db.FILE_RCPTS_LOG.Find(id, id2);
}
```

Remember the order of the keys is important. Hope to help, my friend!

Comment: Hi Tomato32!  Thanks for your reply.   I went ahead and modified the ActionLink as you described.  At that point I am getting an immediate error that I can not use Operator  '+' with Int and and DateTime.

Comment: @ExecChef. Tr:  id= @item.TRACK_NMBR.ToString() +','+@item.TRANS_DT.ToString()

Comment: Perfect!   One last thing.   Now, back in my controller . . .  I am receiving a different error after adding the parse.   The error: 'int?' does not contain a definition for 'Split' and no extension method 'Split' accepting  a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing assembly or reference?).   Do I need to add a reference to use Split?  OR is there an error in my class . . . public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int?)

Comment: @ExecChef: Change Details(string id).

Comment: Thanks Tomato32.  Almost There.   At this point, I am getting a 'A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:). ' Error.   This is the contents of the url string:  http://Base/Details/62%2c10/1/2013%2012%3a00%3a00%20AM.   The parameters it should be passing are Track_Nmbr:  62    Trans_Dt:  2013-10-01

Comment: @ExecChef: Refer the new solution below, my friend. It's easier :))

Comment: Thank you again.  The new solution worked.  It was simple and  easy to implement.  It really helped that your answers were detailed and useful.  Thank you for your help..

Comment: @ExecChef: Yeah! You're great, my friend :))

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are passing the view a model, just return the model in the action link. then you will have everything you need to know, including both Primary keys.

Comment: @Ibraham Malluf:  Thank you for responding.  I think your answer would be beneficial for future use, and I will learn how to do this, as it seems simple enough.  Thank you